# Require a minimum vertical distance when breaking with mdframed

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

I am using the `mdframed` package as shown below within the `Solution` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{Solution}{
    \begin{mdframed}[leftline=true, linecolor=gray, linewidth=3px, backgroundcolor=gray!20, rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false, innerbottommargin=10px, innertopmargin=10px, splittopskip=1.25\baselineskip]
    \textit{Solution.}
    
}{\end{mdframed}

}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

text

    \begin{Solution} 
        This is a solution.
    \end{Solution} 

\end{document}
```

The problem is that sometimes it breaks very awkwardly, such as:

[image]

If it is only a single line *Solution* on the first page, and the rest on the second page, I would rather it just push it to the second page entirely. However, if it is anything longer than a single line of Solution, I want it to keep it on the first page. Setting `nobreak=true` does not work because then it just leaves massive holes when large amounts of text are pushed to the next page.

Is there a way to require a minimum vertical distance before it breaks? Where otherwise it just pushes to the next page?

Some other examples that happen:

[image]

[image]

Comment: use the tcolorbox package. It 's page breaking behaviour is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As "Solution." is visibly a title, it should be preferable to use the `frametitle` key of the [mdframed](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package. The format is set width `frametitlefont`. So add

```tex
  frametitle={Solution.}, frametitlefont=\itshape
```

in your box config. This prevents a break just after the title.

Furthermore, he [mdframed](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package provides `\newmdenv` to define environments. Thus, you can define the `Solution` environment with:

```tex
\newmdenv[leftline=true, linecolor=gray, linewidth=3px,
  backgroundcolor=gray!20,
  rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
  innerbottommargin=10px, innertopmargin=10px,
  splittopskip=1.25\baselineskip,
  frametitle={Solution.},
  frametitlefont=\itshape,
]{Solution}
```

For the second issue, which I couldn't reproduce, maybe look at the `needspace` key. This sets the minimum height before a
frame will be splitted (see doc, section 6.12. General options).

Comment: Thank you so much this worked great! When I put in `frametitle`, the `needspace` wouldn't work perfectly, but `needspace` worked great when I kept Solution as is. I will keep frametitle in mind for the future.